# Extra space below footer

Tags: html, css

I've read several answers regarding this but I couldn't find a suitable answer. I've created a container `div` and created 3 individual `div`s inside it and have positioned them using CSS positioning. At bottom I have a footer `div` but when I load the page in browser, there is extra space below the footer. I don't want to use sticky footer as the contents on my page are loaded dynamically, so the page height changes dynamically.

I think the issue is that the browser adds the height of each div while parsing the page and sets that sum as the height of document. As `div` is a block level element and their flow is one below the other in normal flow.

So, even when the `div`s are positioned using CSS's positioning properties(`top`, `left`, `etc`), the browser still parses them in their normal flow, thus adding up their height (in top-bottom manner of their occurences in normal flow) and thus resulting in extra space below footer as if the internal `div`s (`b`, `c`, `d`) overflows the footer (which they do without positioning).

I just want to know how can I instruct my browser to neglect that extra space.

Here's my Code (see also a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/YpWSM/))

```
<html>
    <head>

        <style>
            #container{width:1000px;height:600px;border:2px solid black;}
            #b{width:200px;height:500px;border:2px solid blue;}
            #c{width:500px;height:500px;border:2px solid green;position:relative;top:-480px;left:247px;}
            #d{width:200px;height:500px;border:2px solid red;position:relative;top:-1005px;left:797px;}
            #footer{width:1000px;height:200px;border:2px solid red;}
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="container">

            <div id="b"><h2>Division_01</h2></div>
            <div id="c"><h2>Division_02</h2></div>
            <div id="d"><h2>Division_03</h2></div>

        </div>

        <div id="footer"><h2>This is my FOOTER....</h2></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` to your CSS

Comment: Why is this tagged with jQuery?

Comment: Its tagged so, bcoz I think maybe,jQuery can come to rescue....

Comment: Using absolute/relative positioning is a very poor way of doing multi-column layouts.  What happens when there's more content than you've allocated space for?

Comment: So what's the best way?
How the websites that contain so much of contents apply layout.I mean they have navigation column to left , then content column in center, then other columns to right, also their advertisements.Which layout technique do they use ??

Comment: @RahulSoni you want to search for "3 column layout". Relative/absolute positioning is probably overkill for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SlightlyCuban Thanks Bro u solved my problem....
Using 3 Column Layout I've my page styled as I wanted it....

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` to your CSS

Or, to be more specific:

```
<style>
    html, body { margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0; }
    #container{width:1000px;height:600px;border:2px solid black;}
    #b{width:200px;height:500px;border:2px solid blue;}
    #c{width:500px;height:500px;border:2px solid green;position:relative;top:-480px;left:247px;}
    #d{width:200px;height:500px;border:2px solid red;position:relative;top:-1005px;left:797px;}
    #footer{width:1000px;height:200px;border:2px solid red;}
</style>
```

Comment: With what you've given as HTML, yes it is. That would be the only given problem. You must have something else you're not showing.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `position: relative` instead of `absolute`. Try giving your `#container` the relative positioning, then use absolute for its children:

```
#container {
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;
    border:2px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
#b {
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    border:2px solid blue;
}
#c {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border:2px solid green;
    position:absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left:247px;
}
#d {
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    border:2px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YpWSM/5/

You were on the right track with how the browser calculates `height` when you use `position: relative`; elements are left in their normal flow, *then* are moved to the offsets.

`position: absolute` *removes* elements from the normal document flow, and positions them according to whatever parent has positioning on it (which is why I added `position: relative` to `#container`).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work

```
 <style>
        #container{width:1000px;height:600px;border:2px solid black;}
        #b{width:200px;height:500px;border:2px solid blue;}
        #c{width:500px;height:500px;border:2px solid green;position:absolute;top:-480px;left:247px;}
        #d{width:200px;height:500px;border:2px solid red;position:absolute;top:-1005px;left:797px;}
        #footer{width:1000px;height:200px;border:2px solid red;}
    </style>
```